# Why does Unity SRP Batcher group objects using one shader into different batches?

Tags: unity-game-engine, optimization

There are 25 buildings in the scene. Each building consists of 123 gameobjects: walls, windows, doors, roof, fence. Each gameobject has its own Mesh Renderer component. There are 3075 gameobjects in total. All gameobjects use the same material, the shader is compatible with SRP Batcher. SRP Batcher in Render Pipeline Asset is turned on. In the Frame Debug window Unity groups draw calls into 12 batches. The more gameobjects in the scene, the more batches. Why does it happen this way, shouldn't all draw calls be grouped into one batch?

[Frame Debug window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UoNoD.png)